# scipy.optimize minimize: Two output variables in objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using the scipy `minimize` function to find the optimal value of some parameters, `H` and `Q`. My objective function, `kalman`, is evaluated on the variable `log_likelihood`. In a nutshell, I am trying to find the optimal values of `H` and `Q` that maximize the variable `log_likelihood`.

In order to do this, scipy's `minimize` function requires that `log_likelihood` be the sole output of my function `kalman`.

My code runs fine and I can find the optimal values of my two parameters `H` and `Q`. What I would like to do, however, is run `kalman` a final time (after optimization) using the optimal `H` and `Q` values and have `kalman` return another variable, `A`, back.

I can't do this because if I set

```
return log_likelihood, A
```

in my `kalman` function, the `minimize` function won't run, because `minimize` can only handle one output from the objective function.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def kalman(x0):

    #set parameters values
    H = x0[0]
    Q = x0[1]

    #Do some operations
    #use H and Q to compute value for variable log_likelihood
    #use H and Q to compute value for variable A
    #...

    return log_likelihood

#initial parameter values
x0 = np.array([np.log(1),np.log(1)])

#optimizing function    
res = minimize(kalman, x0, method='BFGS', options={'disp': True})

#get optimal parameter values
param_values = res.x

#run kalman function final time with optimal values
kalman(param_values)
```

Comment: you can add an extra _optional_ argument to the function, like `kalman(x0,flag=False)`, which causes the function to return more information when set to `True`

Comment: Oh YEAH!!! Thanks! Worked like a charm!